# .Net: SignedXml - Signing xml with transform algorithm exc-c14n

Tags: c#, signedxml

I'm trying to sign Xml (actually SOAP xml) in C# using the [SignedXml class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.aspx), the signing stage passes successfully, but when I try to verify the signature it tells me that it is not valid.
The only change I have done from the example in MSDN that I used [XmlDsigExcC14NTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.xmldsigexcc14ntransform.aspx) instead of the transform XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform.
If I use XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform I will get a valid signature.

Here is my signing code:

```
 private static XmlDocument SignXml(XmlDocument doc)
             {
                 SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
                 signedXml.SigningKey = Certificate.PrivateKey;
    
                 Reference reference = new Reference();
                 reference.Uri = "";
                 
                 XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                 //XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();

                 reference.AddTransform(env);
    
                 signedXml.AddReference(reference);
                 signedXml.ComputeSignature();
    
                 XmlElement signature = signedXml.GetXml();
                 doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(signature);
                 doc.Save(SignedXmlPath);
                 return doc;
             }
```

The above code will give me a valid signature, but if I use

```
XmlDsigExcC14NTransform env = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();
```

instead of

```
XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
```

I will get an invalid signature.

Here is my verification code:

```
private static bool Verify(XmlDocument doc)
        {
            SignedXml signedDoc = new SignedXml(doc);
            XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName(Constants.SignatureElement);

            signedDoc.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);
            return signedDoc.CheckSignature((RSA)Certificate.PublicKey.Key);
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how can I sign with transform algorithm of `http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are gonna need the `XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform` in your case because you are adding the signature inside the element you are signing.

`XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform` will tell the `SignedXml` class to remove the signature from the signature node itself before testing it's validity. This is needed because you added that element after calculating the signature.

You can add more then one transform by calling the `AddTransform` again like this:

```
XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
XmlDsigExcC14NTransform c14n = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform();

reference.AddTransform(env);
reference.AddTransform(c14n);
```

However i think what you actually want to do instead of my example above is set the `CanonicalizationMethod` to c14n:

```
signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#";
 - or - 
signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
```

Comment: Thank you Jan for your answer. I understand now.
Actually I need to sign the body in SOAP message and then I will add the signature to Security header in the SOAP envelope. So if I do that I will be able to use XmlDsigExcC14NTransform because then the Signature element will not be a part of the signed one. right?
Thanks again...

Comment: Thank you. I had a similar case and also needed: c14n.Algorithm = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;